# How do I change my SVN account in subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am running eclipse Version: 3.5.2 Build id: M20100211-1343
with the subclipse plugin 1.6.4
I have saved my password, but now I need to change the account I connect with.

How do I do that?

My coworker has Version: Helios Release Build id: 20100617-1415 and subclipse 1.6.14 but no Application data folder.

Where might subclipse hide its config data if there is no Application Data folder?

Comment: Did you try right-click on project -> team -> disconnect ?

Comment: I think that it will just disconnect the project from SVN, not forget the user account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to clean the Subversion credentials storage:

~/.subversion/auth on Linux and OSX
USER_HOME\Application Data\Subversion\auth\svn.simple directory on Windows

You may also want to read the excellent article on changing credentials here:

[Changing subclipse credentials on Windows](http://www.java-tips.org/blog/subversion/subclipse-changing-user-credentials.html)
[Changing subclipse credentials on Linux/OSX](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/PluginFAQ#head-d507c29676491f4419997a76735feb6ef0aa8cf8) [Under 1.7 (Usernames and Passwords)]

Comment: I have the USER_HOME/Application Data folder. But my coworker with the problem does not.

Comment: Something goofy about windows permissions and not being able to see the folder. All is well now

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu the files in ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server were just trusted SSL certs. You want to locate a file called .keyring (mine was eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.keyring) and delete that- next time you try to interact with your SVN repo you will be prompted for your credentials.

Referenced from: http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/PluginFAQ#head-d507c29676491f4419997a76735feb6ef0aa8cf8